# How to convert or parse a Gherkin Feature FIle into JSON object using Python

Tags: python, json, gherkin

How to convert or parse a Gherkin Feature FIle into JSON object using Python
I have a Cucumber Gherkin file that needs to be converted into JSON object. I am using Python dictionary and json library and file object.

```
from pytest_bdd import scenario
```

Can you please clarify why this is giving an error?

Comment: Please add the error that the given line of code causes. Make sure you do a bit of reasearch on the type of error to get an idea what it means. Also, are you sure you mean "JSON object" and not "Python dict"? What does the Gherking file look like, what JSON do you expect it to become? Make sure you provide a [mcve] of code and data. Also, as a new user here, read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

from pytest_bdd import scenario
"""
data = {}  # fix same keys by just putting vals
data["Feature"] = "A site where you can publish your articles"
data["Scenarios"] = {
    "Scenario": "Publishing the article",

    "Given": "I'm an author user",
    "GivenAnds": ["I have an article", "go here"],

    "When": "I go to article",
    "WhenAnds":["I press publish button", "go here"],

    "Then": "I should not see the error message",
    "ThenAnds":["article should be published", "go here"]


}"""

def program():
    data = {}
    file = open("myfeature.feature", "r+")
    feature = ""

    data["Feature"] = None
    data["Scenarios"] = {
        "Given": None,
        "GivenAnds": [],

        "When": None,
        "WhenAnds":[],

        "Then": None,
        "ThenAnds":[]
    }

    file_lines = []  # each element is a line ni file
    with open("myfeature.feature", 'r+') as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            file_lines.append(line)
    cur_statement = None
    for i, line in enumerate(file_lines):
        if "Feature: " in line:
            feature = line.split("Feature: ", 1)[1]
            data["Feature"] = feature
        if "Scenario" in line:
            scenario = line.split("Scenario: ", 1)[1]
            data["Scenarios"]["Scenario"] = scenario
        if "Given " in line: 
            given = line.split("Given ", 1)[1]
            data["Scenarios"]["Given"] = given
            cur_statement = "Given "
        if "When " in line: 
            when = line.split("When ", 1)[1]
            data["Scenarios"]["When"] = when
            cur_statement = "When "
        if "Then " in line: 
            then = line.split("Then ", 1)[1]
            data["Scenarios"]["Then"] = then
            cur_statement = "Then "

        if "And " in line:
            if cur_statement == "Given ":
                g_and = line.split("And ", 1)[1]
                data["Scenarios"]["GivenAnds"].append(g_and)
            if cur_statement == "When ":
                w_and = line.split("And ", 1)[1]
                data["Scenarios"]["WhenAnds"].append(w_and)
            if cur_statement == "Then ":
                t_and = line.split("And ", 1)[1]
                data["Scenarios"]["ThenAnds"].append(t_and)

    print("\n")
    print(data)

    print("\n")
    json_data = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
    print(json_data)


program()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

data = {}
data["Feature"] = "A site where you can publish your articles"
data["Scenarios"] = {
    "Publishing the article":{
        "Given": "I'm an author user",    
        "GivenAnds": ["I have an article", "ok go"],
        "When": "I go to the article page",
        "WhenAnds": ["I press the publish button", "ok go"],
        "Then": "I should not see the error message",
        "ThenAnds": ["article should be published", "ok go"]

    }
}

class Scenario:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.given = None
        self.when = None
        self.then = None
        self.given_ands = []
        self.then_ands = []
        self.when_ands = []

def program():
    data = {"Feature": None, "Scenarios": {}}
    file = open("myfeature.feature", "r+")
    feature = ""

    
    file_lines = []  # each element is a line ni file
    with open("myfeature.feature", 'r+') as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            file_lines.append(line)

    scenario_objs = []
    cur_scenario = None
    cur_statement = None
    for i, line in enumerate(file_lines):
        if "Feature: " in line:
            feature = line.split("Feature: ", 1)[1]
        if "Scenario" in line:
            name = line.split("Scenario: ", 1)[1]
            s1 = Scenario(name)
            cur_scenario = s1
            scenario_objs.append(s1)
        if "Given " in line: 
            given = line.split("Given ", 1)[1]
            cur_scenario.given = given
            cur_statement = "Given "
        if "When " in line: 
            when = line.split("When ", 1)[1]
            cur_scenario.when = when
            cur_statement = "When "
        if "Then " in line: 
            then = line.split("Then ", 1)[1]
            cur_scenario.then = then
            cur_statement = "Then "

        if "And " in line:
            if cur_statement == "Given ":
                g_and = line.split("And ", 1)[1]
                cur_scenario.given_ands.append(g_and)
            if cur_statement == "When ":
                w_and = line.split("And ", 1)[1]
                cur_scenario.when_ands.append(w_and)
            if cur_statement == "Then ":
                t_and = line.split("And ", 1)[1]
                cur_scenario.then_ands.append(t_and)

    for s in scenario_objs:
        data["Feature"] = feature
        data["Scenarios"][s.name] = {}
        data["Scenarios"][s.name]["Given"] = s.given
        data["Scenarios"][s.name]["When"] = s.when
        data["Scenarios"][s.name]["Then"] = s.then
        data["Scenarios"][s.name]["GivenAnds"] = s.given_ands
        data["Scenarios"][s.name]["ThenAnds"] = s.then_ands
        data["Scenarios"][s.name]["WhenAnds"] = s.when_ands



    print("\n")
    print(data)

    print("\n")
    json_data = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
    print(json_data)


program()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).